# ASP.Net MVC is it passive model or active model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As the subject states, is the mvc model that is used in ASP.Net MVC an active or passive model and why.

Comment: I'd say: this depends on the implementation. Usually it's passive. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@joa. I've read up on the website at the link provided and you are indeed correct.
VS2010 creates a passive asp.net mvc project for you. Its then up to you to modify it into an active mvc model.
By default dev's go along with the passive model (looking at the many, many examples of asp.net mvc). Implementing the active model requires a bit more work though.
Ref: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html